# Cannot find 'CallKitProviderDelegate' in scope from AppDelegate

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to implement SIP calls within [VialerSIPLib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS6Rz.png)

Im newbie in ios development.

I have successfully run example project but I have an issue when trying to add library into my project.

Installation instruction is saying that all we need to do is install lib with CocoaPods. For a testing I have created new project from the scratch and install/update pod

```
pod 'VialerSIPLib'
```

but still I'm unable to use library in AppDelegate.

```
Cannot find 'CallKitProviderDelegate' in scope.
```

How can I make AppDelegate to see pod dependencies ?

I'm using xcode 12 and swift 5. Target os is 14.0
Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Missing `#import VialerSIPlib` in `AppDelegate.swift`?

Comment: I have already tried that - then it's saying No such module 'VialerSIPlib'
In addition in example file they dont have to do this import 
https://github.com/VoIPGRID/VialerSIPLib/blob/develop/Example/VialerSIPLib/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Did you imitate https://github.com/VoIPGRID/VialerSIPLib/blob/develop/Example/VialerSIPLib/VialerSIPLib_Example-Bridging-Header.h ? I don't even see your bridging header in the screen shot. Also you still need to import the module in Swift?

Comment: Exactly :) I have found that too :) couple minutes ago :) thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

OK I have found a root cause - I've been missing bridge between objective C and swift. More information is present here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift